# Is there a Stack Exchange site for asking questions about Google apps?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The closest site I could find for Google related questions is Android Enthusiasts.  I would like to ask a question about Google Voice & Hangouts.  It does have an Android app but it's not a question about the Android OS; only the app.  Is there a more appropriate site than Android Enthusiasts to ask such a question?

Comment: [android.se] isn't just for the OS; it's also for apps.

Comment: I've proposed a Google StackExchange site here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/115799/google

Comment: It is possible to create new stack exchange websites at a website named "[area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)". I recommend that you propose a new stack exchange site for Google products.

Comment: The Stack Exchange site named [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is dedicated to teaching people how to do things in programs intended for use on the the Microsoft Windows operating system. The site named [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is for questions about programme designed to run on a computer with the Apple Operating System. It seems like we could create a Stack Exchange site for programmes created by Google.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While Google services are generally web-based, virtually anything they put on a smartphone is a native app, and would thus be off-topic at Web Applications. You'll be better off at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) or [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com).

To wit:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts

That said, if you want to ask about the actual web interface for Google's myriad apps, then [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) is the place.

Comment: What about Google hardware, like Google Home, Chromebooks, or Chromecasts? I tried Super User but I've already been downvoted minutes later.

Comment: Chromebooks are on-topic at [su], but the rest don't really have a home at Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

For anything related to Android, *[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)* is indeed the best option.

Programming questions involving the Google API are best asked at *[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)*.

Most other Google related questions are best suited for *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)*.

Comment: What about Google hardware, like Google Home, Chromebooks, or Chromecasts? I tried Super User but I've already been downvoted minutes later.

Comment: @AaronFranke: Super User should have been fine, could you please link to the questions?

Answer (score 2):

In addition, aside from Voice, Google App Engine Python questions are, I believe, on Stack  Overflow with the [google-appengine-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine-python) tag. Google announced a while back they were outsourcing some elements of free support to here. I see some other `google-app*` tags too.